# Multicolumn UITableView implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multiple-columns

I have been unsuccessful in finding a implementation of the UITableView with multiple columns.. My requirement is not to use images in multicolumn, but rather use it more like a spreadsheet, with 6 columns and variable rows and with alternating colors. Any pointers as to how I can achieve this, UICollectionView examples all show images, I could not get it to do something like a spreadsheet. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a project that seems to acomplish what you're looking for...

[MDSpreadView](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView)

[MSSpreadView Demo](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadViewDemo)

Last update was pre iOS7, but it should point you in the right direction.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard component to handle what you're looking for. Use a UITableView and subclass UITableViewCell. Say you call it MCTableViewCell, while setting up MCTableViewCell iterate through the amount of "columns" you want and add subviews representing each cell to the MCTableViewCell's content view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this:

[image]

You should definitely check this awesome post: http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

Also you can directly go to their source code from here: https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Implemented in obj-c both they recently migrated to swift. They are using UICollectionView as you can see the details from the post.